# PHP & MySQL username storage and cookie

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, hash

How to securely store usernames in database, without adding them directly to cookie value?

> **Example:**
>   I want to display username of logged user.
>   If he have closed his browser early the only way to do this is $_COOKIE['cookie name']
>   where cookie value links with username in database.
>   So I don' t need to hash username.

Is it right? And if it's right, is it secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is assuming you are talking about a persistent login feature using cookies. For the purpose of just remembering the user name (but not signing them in automatically), having a username in the cookie (optionally encoded) should be okay though. Regardless, passwords should never be in the cookie.

---

Cookies should NOT be directly identifying, i.e. user ids / names should not appear in the cookie. Instead, you should assign a sufficiently long enough string with random data to the users in your table and store that in the cookie value. Once used you should update the string and issue another cookie.

For example:

```
john | ewojroj1234ojqewor
jack | ljqwelkn1k31n23k33
```

The second column will be placed in the cookie. Later you will query that value against the user table and:

1. fetch the user data and store inside a session
2. regenerate the random string
3. issue another cookie

Password changes and signing out should also cause a change in the user token string.

For further reading, Barry Jaspan wrote a [good article](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice) on this approach.

Comment: Is it the best way to generate second column every time after user signing in?

Comment: I assume that the use of storing the cookie is to enable the user to reopen the browser at a later stage, type in a password and get authenticate. This requires this jumble of characters (to identify the user) along with the password being sent to the server. How does knowing the username differ from knowing this jumble of characters make it more secure?

Comment: @EdHeal admitedly, I assumed that OP wanted a persistent login feature (i.e. without password)

Comment: @warlord I wasn't sure whether you are using that cookie to automatically log a person in when he comes back on your site.

Comment: @Jack I use cookies for this purpose exactly

Comment: @warlord I've updated my answer based on that new information :)

Answer (score 2):

It is secure. Just do not store the password on the client (browser). Also never send the password to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can store the username in the cookie, this is safe as long as you do not save the password there.
2. You can also save there user **id**, then it does not give away any of the authentication details while letting you find the correct user.
3. Use [`sessions`](http://php.net/sessions). data stored in `$_SESSION` is stored on **server**, not on client.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to store only the user_id (the uniquely identifying primary key) of the user table in the $_COOKIE or $_SESSION variable - perhaps in $_COOKIE['user_id'].

Then on each page load, you can use that id to retrieve any  user information you wish from the database. For example (Note this is conceptual/psuedo-code only. You would of course sanitize/clean/validate/bind the $_COOKIE or $_SESSION data parameter first):

`SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id']`